# Disable expanding of all top level nodes of a treeview

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

How can a gtk+ treeview be configured so that only the top level nodes are visible, and their expansion is disabled? With this configuration there will be no way of seing any child node.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use model *filter* (`GtkTreeModelFilter` gtk [2](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html),[3](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html)) as a front-end to data model and simply filter all level > 1 nodes unless data model is huge.